# Failed to get convolution algorithm.This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize.[{node conv2d_1/Conv2D}]

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

**Error**
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node conv2d_1/Conv2D (defined at C:\Users\Rajshree\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_808]

I'm running 2 programs . Both are using this and performing similar task of recognizing human expression. The difference only lies in the model of CNN they are using. One is working perfectly fine so what could be the possible problem with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to a multitude of things. Are you running the two programs at the same time? Are you running this on a GPU? If so, it could be that one is already using the GPU, and the other finds that the GPU is already in use so it throws an error.

Comment: I'm not running the two together. They are completely independent.